# How to override a block generated by a module?

Tags: 7, theming

The PCP module has a pcp-block.tpl.php file in it's module directory that generates a block output.
To change that output I [read](http://drupal.org/node/173880) that I could just copy this file into the "templates" folder of my current theme and it would take precedence over the one in the module directory. But it's not working. I did clear the theme registry cache.
How do I get it to work?

Comment: turns out it's a bug in that module

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you copied block.tpl.php to your template directory as well? In Drupal 6 you need to have the base form before a more specific template will be used. For example before region-sidebar.tpl.php takes, you need region.tpl.php; before node-story.tpl.php, you need node.tpl.php. In D6 the block.tpl.php is in modules/system/.

I don't use D7, and it could've changed as David G. says.

Comment: no. Why would I need to do that and where do I copy it from?

Comment: have updated answer - don't know if it'll work for D7

Comment: thanks, but it didn't work, see above comments

Answer (score 1):

I guess it should work if you placed the same tpl file in your corresponding folder. Also please make sure that you saved the theme configuration settings.

Comment: Removed advertising link.  Please read the [FAQ](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: I copied the block.tpl.php from the core block module into my bartik templates directory, flushed the cache and saved the theme configuration settings. It still doesn't show the modified pcp-block.tpl.php

Answer (score 0):

In D6 in order to override theme templates the base template needs to be in your  folder for your local overrides to be seen. I was under the impression this was not needed in D7.